# When does the getView finished invoked?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I save the listview items position in a set in adapter method "getView", 
which saves the current displaying items position,

but I can't get the set content after invoking setAdapter(myAdapter),
It seems that it's multi-thread, 
if that, when can i get the set content.

Comment: not sure i understand your question/goal exactly but...getView is a callback within your adapter which i believe is called everytime the listview requires to populate another list view item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can't get the set content after invoking setAdapter(myAdapter), It seems that it's multi-thread, if that,

It is not "multi-thread". However, the `Adapter` will not be immediately used when you call `setAdapter()`, any more than a `TextView` will be immediately updated when you call `setText()`. All GUI events are processed by the main application thread based off of a work queue -- calls to `setAdapter()` will not take effect until after whatever block of code you are in returns.

Comment: Thanks, I have to turn to other way.